# Laravel Statamic app not loading images on live, works fine on local host. Have tried storage:link and all other solutions

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, statamic

As mentioned, the src’s for my images in a Laravel Statamic app on the digital ocean app platform just aren’t coming through. The alt text is there. These images work absolutely fine on local which I see as a common issue posted, I’ve tried all the fixes but none have worked for me.

- Have ensured that all my asset disks have urls and are public
- Have done storage:link
- Have increased the php memory limit with user ini - and verified it worked
- Set env variables for url, app key within Digital Ocean etc
- Have NOT tried deleting the public storage folder as honestly, I don’t know how to do that on live through the console

I do think it’s an issue with the symlink in the file below, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. I’m sure it’s something simple but am banging my head against a wall figuring this out.

Any and all advice very welcome! Thanks!

Filesystems.php:

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'images'),

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
        'url' => '/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images'),
        'url' => '/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'favicons' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('favicons'),
        'url' => '/favicons',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'files' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('files'),
        'url' => '/files',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'social_images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('social_images'),
        'url' => '/social_images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Symbolic Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
| `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
| the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
|
*/

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

];

Comment: have you tried cache clear, php artisan cache:clear
php please cache:clear
,  also check for  file permissions . also debug the image path by printing it , may possibility of path issue

Comment: when you tried storage link did you run the command `php artisan storage:link`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible checks:

1. Check File Permissions: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

2. Verify Storage Link:
   Ensure that the symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public exists. You can check this by running the following command: `ls -l public`
3. Check Image URLs in Templates:
   Ensure that the image URLs in your Statamic templates are correct. You may use asset tag or Laravel's asset helper function.
   `<img src="{{ asset('images/your-image.jpg') }}" alt="Alt text">`
4. Asset URLs in Disk Configuration:
   In your filesystems.php configuration, update the url for the 'images' disk to use the correct URL:

   `'images' => [ 'driver' => 'local', 'root' => public_path('images'), 'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images', 'visibility' => 'public', ],`
5. Clear Configuration Cache: `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thank you for the tips!

2. the symlink appears to be there and valid: